# Как сделать создание таблиц по клику на button? при этом пользователь сам вводит шырину и высоту таблицы, количество рядов и столбцов

Tags: javascript, html, css

нужно чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "создать таблицу", создавалась таблица со всеми настройками которые ввел пользователь

[image]

Я решыл это задание а удалить невозможно. Поетому пишу решение может комуто будет нужно. Также написал вопрос конкретнее

```
getId('createTable').onclick = function(){

    let trTable = getId('rowElementsTable').value;
    let tdTable = getId('colElementsTable').value;
    let widthTable = getId('widthColTable').value;
    let heightTable = getId('heightColTable').value;
    let weightTable = getId('weightLine').value;
    let typeLine = getId('lineType').value;
    let colorLine = getId('lineColor').value;


    getId('optionBox').style.display = 'none';
    getId('mainBoxes').style.display = 'block';

    getId('textArea').value += '<table style="border:'+weightTable+'px '+typeLine+' '+colorLine+'">';

    for(let i = 1; i<=trTable; i++){

        getId('textArea').value += '<tr>';

        for(let i = 1; i<=tdTable; i++){
            getId('textArea').value += '<td style="width: '+widthTable+'px; height:'+heightTable+'px; border:'+weightTable
        +'px '+typeLine+' '+colorLine+'">some text</td>';
        }
        getId('textArea').value += '</tr>';
    }
    getId('textArea').value += '</table>';

}
```

Comment: мб поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347542/generate-table-based-on-number-of-rows-columns-in-jquery, https://gist.github.com/jineeshjohn/2044414

Comment: нужно все сделать на чистом javascript

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Код в студию!!!

Comment: @Bharata Извиняюсь конечно что, плохо написал условия. но мне не нужен код с решением. мне нужно понять каков правильный алгоритм работы етого задания.

Comment: Решение опубликуйте ответом.  Вопрос поправте, что бы была видна попытка решения.

Comment: Перенеси ответ в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```
getId('createTable').onclick = function(){

    let trTable = getId('rowElementsTable').value;
    let tdTable = getId('colElementsTable').value;
    let widthTable = getId('widthColTable').value;
    let heightTable = getId('heightColTable').value;
    let weightTable = getId('weightLine').value;
    let typeLine = getId('lineType').value;
    let colorLine = getId('lineColor').value;


    getId('optionBox').style.display = 'none';
    getId('mainBoxes').style.display = 'block';

    getId('textArea').value += '<table style="border:'+weightTable+'px '+typeLine+' '+colorLine+'">';

    for(let i = 1; i<=trTable; i++){

        getId('textArea').value += '<tr>';

        for(let i = 1; i<=tdTable; i++){
            getId('textArea').value += '<td style="width: '+widthTable+'px; height:'+heightTable+'px; border:'+weightTable
        +'px '+typeLine+' '+colorLine+'">some text</td>';
        }
        getId('textArea').value += '</tr>';
    }
    getId('textArea').value += '</table>';

}
```

Comment: getId -- function getId(a){
 return document.getElementById(a);
}